# Using WorksheetFunction.Match on a non ordered list and not exact

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have two workbooks, and both shave a list of ALMOST the same items. One of the list has a few extra spaces at the end of its list and it's throwing me completely off.

```
Public Sub test() 'Imports data into M&R spreadsheet
Dim wbMnR As Workbook
Dim wbMatch As Workbook
Set wbMnR = Workbooks("MnRs.xlsx")
Set wbMatch = Workbooks("Match.xlsm")

Dim myRow As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
    myRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(wbMatch.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & CStr(i)), wbMnR.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0)
    Debug.Print myRow
Next i

End Sub
```

The item list in copy is

```
 "R-01"
 "R-02"
 "R-03"
 "R-04"
```

the item list in paste is

```
 "R-01 "
 "R-03"
 "R-02"
 "R-04 "
```

These are just examples I made up and for various reasons I can't input my actual data. I cannot sort my list in the MnR worksheet though since the workbook I was given contains some merge cells and various data which separates specific sections. With the way Match works, I know that using a perfect match of "0" will not work because of the extra space, but using a "1" or "-1" will not work either because my list cannot be sorted.

Comment: Try `R-01*` . A [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) can use the **0** *range_lookup* with a wildcard. Just watch out for `R-011`.

Comment: Would I do that by just saying match (blah & "*", array,0)? I will have -11.. how would i differentiate between the two? With an if statement?

Comment: Yes, that should match *blah<space>* and *blah-blah*. `R-01*` won't match `R-11` but it will match `R-011`.

Comment: What about accounting for -011, I do have items on the list that are like this for some dumb reason.. is there a way to make the wildcard only count if it's a space?

Comment: There is usually some band-aid type work-around but I cannot give specifics on logic without seeing real data and that is not an option. I'm sorry, but I have no wish to play 20 questions when I cannot see the playing field. Mixed metaphor, I know... but appropriate.

Comment: I looked at your function and I would suggest you match on no traling space and if [IsError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx) reports an error then try to match with a trailing space. Better yet, get rid of the trailing spaces. See [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: If there's a way to only make the wildcard count for spaces, that would make it work for everything I need. Basically my data contains r-01 thru 06 and r-011 thru -018. everything from 011 thru 018 would cause an issue. If that option is not available, then would the best course be to just make a robust if statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103497/discussion-between-niseonna-and-jeeped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx).

```
With wbMatch.Worksheets(1)
    For i = 1 To 10
        myRow = 0
        Select Case False
            Case IsError(Application.Match(.Range("a" & i), wbMnR.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0))
                myRow = Application.Match(.Range("a" & i), wbMnR.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0)
            Case IsError(Application.Match(.Range("a" & i) & Chr(32), wbMnR.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0))
                myRow = Application.Match(.Range("a" & i) & Chr(32), wbMnR.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0)
            Case Else
                'nothing found
        End Select
        Debug.Print myRow
    Next i
End With
```

If you run into further trouble, that Select Case will be easier to expand upon. To make this more efficient, the most common matches should be at the top of the Case statements.